# A word or term for "delivered upon request"

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a machine, that delivers items to users.

Sometimes the machine delivers items that were not requested by the user.

I refer to these as "*excess items*". What would be a good word or term for items that are delivered upon request? I'm looking for alternatives to "*requested items*", that entail that the item was both requested and delivered.

Comment: _requested deliveries_?

Comment: I'd like to keep the word "item" and have the first word entail more than the request

Comment: Order fullfilled.

Comment: How about "on-demand".

Comment: @Jim Simson, I guess that would work. thank you